# Phonegap Windows Phone 8 White Space at the bottom solution not working

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, viewport

I am developing a Phonegap App for Windows Phone 8. I am testing my app on two devices, the HTC Windows Phone 8S and the Nokia Lumia 820. My App is displayed correctly on the HTC device but it leaves a white space at the bottom of the Nokia Device. I can only assume, this is where the address bar would be present in the web view.

The solution I have at the moment removes the white space at the bottom but presents another problem.

```
body, html { 
-ms-overflow-style: none !important;
}

@-ms-viewport {
height:513px;
width: 320px;
user-zoom: fixed;
max-zoom: 1;
min-zoom: 1;
}
```

It does get rid of the white space at the bottom but when I click on an input field within my app, the width of the app adjusts to the device width.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Include this in Index.html,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

Include this in CSS:

```
@viewport
{
width:320px;
}

@-ms-viewport {
width:320px;
zoom-user:fixed;
max-zoom:1;
min-zoom:1;
}
```

and include also this,

```
body, html { 
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important; 
}
```

This will solve the issue for now, it worked for me in the same situation..!!
:-)

Comment: Sorry - I edited my answer and un-deleted it. hope my answer helps..!!